# @OneToOne is failing for Null @JoinColumn JPA

Tags: rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa

While inserting the employee record through Postman, i am getting following exception.

I have following tables:
1. emp_boarding_detail -> Has subcon_id coulmn and subcon_id can be null.
2. suncon_details table - Having subcon_id as Primary Key 
3. Some other tables also

**Exception:**
"org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.boarding.preboardingentities.Empboardingdetails.subcondetails -> com.boarding.preboardingentities.Subcondetails; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.boarding.preboardingentities.Empboardingdetails.subcondetails -> com.boarding.preboardingentities.Subcondetails"

In EmpboardingDetails entity class, I have defined relationship as following[image]:

And this is my SubconDetails entity class:

[image]

As subcon_id can be null, so I have added new column id in SubconDetail class. Is it the right approach? I am getting below exception when I am not passing SubconDetail as following:

Part of my Post Request(Postman):
 "sub_con_id" : {
    "sub_con_id" : "",
    "subcontractor_or_companyname" : "",
    "w2payer_company" : ""
  },

Comment: you should post your code directly instead of having pictures, to be more readable;

Answer (score 0):

Most likely problem is that when you try to persist Most EmpboardingDetails entity, SubconDetail entity does not exist in persistence context;

For this to work, either you have to create SubconDetail beforehand or put the following in EmpBoardingDetails class

```
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Also take a look at this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types)